# авторизация на файлах

Tags: php

```
$email_acc = file_get_contents("../../acc/$id/info/email.dat");
$pass_acc = file_get_contents("../../acc/$id/info/pass.dat");
$nickname_acc = file_get_contents("../../acc/$id/info/nickname.dat");
```

`../../acc/$id/info/` - это путь с данными от акаунта
если пароль и логин не совпадают, все нормально -  пишет "неправильный пароль", но если я ввожу правильно, пишет

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at "путь":49) in "путь" on line 83

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at "путь":49) in "путь" on line 84

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at "путь":49) in "путь" on line 85<br>
на этих линиях код такой: <br>
setcookie("id","$id", time() + 99999999, "/");<br>
                            setcookie("nickname","$nickname_acc", time() + 99999999, "/");<br>
                            header( 'Location: ../../', true, 307 );



                    <form action='index.php' method='post'>
                        <input type='email' name='email'>
                        <input type='password' name='pass'>
                        <input type='submit'>
                    </form>
```

```
            if($_POST)
            {
                $count_id = file_get_contents('../register/count_id.dat');
                for($i=1; $i<$count_id; $i++)
                {
                    $id = "id".$i;
                    $email_acc = file_get_contents("../../acc/$id/info/email.dat");
                    $pass_acc = file_get_contents("../../acc/$id/info/pass.dat");
                    $nickname_acc = file_get_contents("../../acc/$id/info/nickname.dat");

                    if($pass == $pass_acc and $email == $email_acc)
                    {
                        setcookie("id","$id", time() + 99999999, "/");
                        setcookie("nickname","$nickname_acc", time() + 99999999, "/");
                        header( 'Location: ../../', true, 307 );
                        break;
                        echo "ok";

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo
                        '
                            <h4>Неправильний логін або пароль!</h4>
                        ';
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>[![весь код простите что украинский делаю укр сайт][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

заголовки http-ответа нельзя отослать после того как вы начали выдачу данных тела ответа.
если у вас код формы выводится раньше выдачи заголовков, то ничего и не получится, вам надо разделить выдачу данных и проверку условий
т.е. если успешно залогинились, ставим `$success=1;`  и позднее проверяем, если `($success)` то не выводим форму.

в остальном, код конечно страшный, но если вы просто учитесь, то ок.

```
весь код простите что украинский делаю укр сайт
```

мы итак видим, что это код на иностранном языке, зачем вы извиняетесь?

Comment: это ошыбка сайта там должна была быть фотка но багнуло не оброщайте внимания

Comment: а где нужно ставить $success=1; при обновлении страницы переменная станет по дефолту ноликом

Comment: при обновлении вы, я так, понимаю, уже в куку смотрите, если выставлена, то $success=1, иначе 0;

Comment: понимаете у меня куки не сетится как вы видите

Comment: не сетится потому, что вывод происходит до выставления кук, перенесите его ниже